# Lazy loading and eager loading - how can I check that?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have POCO entity type:

```
public class Blog 
{  
    public int BlogId { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Url { get; set; }  
    public string Tags { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }  
}
```

How can I check in Visual Studio debugger that this query gets only Blogs:

```
var result1 = context.Blog.ToList();
```

And this query gets Blogs together with Posts as part of the query:

```
var result2 = context.Blog.Include(x => x.Posts).ToList();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

On the context look for a property regarding lazy loading (context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled) and with it disabled,
Add a watch on result1.Posts, and nothing should have been loaded.

Conversely result2.Posts should, given inspection, have items. 
Of course, this relies on entries in the database being wired up!

Another tell tale sign is a proxy object on the Posts, collection which will have a strange name, if lazy loading is enabled.

Comment: In both cases: result1 and result2 have got Posts.

Comment: So have you done those checks I mentioned? Ive just updated post to include the property. I couldnt remember it off the top of my head.

Comment: I have enabled lazy loading and I have added watch to result1 and result2.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the debugger is not the right place to be monitoring stuff like this. Instead, I would use SQL Server Profiler or a specialty tool like [EFProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof).

Answer (score 0):

Of course the dilemma is that as soon as you address blog.Posts you will get items, but at that moment you can't tell anymore when/how they were loaded. (If you're not monitoring SQL).

You can be 100% sure if you check the local collection:

```
var result1 = context.Blog.ToList();
var postsLoaded = context.Posts.Local.Any(); // false.


var result2 = context.Blog.Include(x => x.Posts).ToList();
var postsLoaded = context.Posts.Local.Any(); // true. 
// (if Blogs having Posts were loaded)
```